# build a production site with bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I have built a REST API using Python and Bottle web framework. I have tested it locally and it works well according to my needs. I now need to take it online and have multiple people accessing it, maybe concurrently, to upload video files to be processed.

I have read in the bottle documentation information regarding deployment and it seems to me that all I should do is use a load balancer (for example using Pond) and have several bottle processes ready in different ports of my server waiting for clients to arrive.

Is this correct? If, let's say, I open 4 ports with 4 bottle processes, can I be sure that 4 clients will be able to submit their videos concurrently using the same input url+port and not experience any delays?

Comment: Did you try it? The more intersting question ist: can your backend handle the load of four concurrent video uploads?

Comment: I suspect there should not be a problem on load, but I cound be wrong...

Comment: You should be using a production-level webserver, not Python's built-in HTTP server.  Consider nginx/uwsgi, Apache, gunicorn, et al.